# Deploying report <timeFrameFilter> <dateColumn> <interval> "Last 2 Days" - not possible in UI or Metadata API?

Tags: reporting, deployment, metadata-api, custom-report-type

[image]

Before I chalked this very simple reporting request to not being possible, I thought would check on here.

I'd like to have a running report pull in a date field where the value could be the "Last 2 Days" however I'm not sure if this is entirely possible?

Obviously I could have the user manually select a date timeframe every time they run the report... but I'd really like to ensure they don't have to manually edit it and could utilize the "running" Date Field functionality.

I get the following errors when using the metadata API:

```
    <timeFrameFilter>
        <dateColumn>Opportunity$Date_Opportunity_Triaged__c</dateColumn>
        <interval>INTERVAL_AGO2D</interval><!--similar to the "Last 2 Years" Format - INTERVAL_AGO2Y-->
    </timeFrameFilter>
```

problem: Error parsing file: 'INTERVAL_AGO2D' is not a valid value for the enum

```
    <timeFrameFilter>
        <dateColumn>Opportunity$Date_Opportunity_Triaged__c</dateColumn>
        <interval>INTERVAL_LAST2</interval><!--Last 7 Days-->
    </timeFrameFilter>
```

problem: Error parsing file: 'INTERVAL_LAST2' is not a valid value for the enum

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new formula field (Number) with the following formula:

```
TODAY () - Date_Opportunity_Triaged__c
```

Then I used the following 2 filters and that solved my issue to get YESTERDAY and TODAY / LAST_2_DAYS in a report.

[image]